# sqoop export java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I have created a table with below format in the hive

`create table test(id int, name string, age int) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';`

`id                      int
name                    string
age                     int`

I have loaded the below data from text file into the hive table

`1,abc,10
2,xyz,20
3,def,30`

I have validated the table and data is loaded fine.
Now I created a table in MySQL with below columns and tried to sqoop export from hive to MySQL and it failed with **java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string**. Can you guys let me know what is the mistake I am doing?

`create table test1(id int,age int);`

My Sqoop Command

```
sqoop export \
--connect  \
--username  \
--password  \
--export-dir location \
--table test \
--columns id,age \
--fields-terminated-by ","
```

Comment: Order of the columns are also very important while exporting the data per suppose if you created the mysql table with columns names as id,name which are in the same as hive table and then try to export the data it will successfully exports to mysql table. 

I do not know whether there is an option to export even though the columns are not in order hope some one from the community answers this one all the best

Comment: what is that you want to achieve? want to export data from `hdfs` or export from `hive` table, both have subtle difference.

Comment: @Gaurang I have a table in hive with 3 columns and I want this table to be exported to MySQL database but I only want the last two columns of the hive table Can I achieve it?

Comment: @Johny_Bravo Have you solved this ? I found this error too with less columns in Hive than Oracle, let says on HIve I have c,d,e and on Oracle I have a,b,c,d,e and I want to export by update just e with c,d as update-keys.